# Bare metal windows 2008

Tags: windows

The question is if the system on the server or hardware failure after restoring a bare metal backup to a new machine what will hapen with custom programs and settings non microsoft in that backup, will it they work after restoring?

Answer (score 6):

That's the million dollar question, isn't it?

...which is why backups should be considered completely useless until you've tested restoration successfully.

There's no obvious reason that non-MS software and data would be skipped, but this all is dependent on how you have things configured. Which goes back to the need to test restores.

Comment: Ok, ok. But how the bare metal works ??

Comment: That's a completely different question. You can create a new question to ask it, but please do your own research before asking, otherwise it will likely get down voted and closed.

Comment: I understand. Its a question releated to existing one. If bare metal restore complete system then it would be logical that will restore an existing installed programs

Comment: Try a backup. Then test it. You will learn a lot about the process while doing this.

Comment: Begs for a reversal badge...

Comment: Mac sa dve ostrice. In other words no one know "as i can see" how bare metal REALY WORK.